# Material Component Tabs Item size in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tabs

[image]

I want to automatically resize the items to fit the number of UITabBarItem. However, the size of the item is not automatically adjusted.
I would like to have two items full of tab bar, three of them full of tab bar.

Currently, the tab bar has an item, but the tab bar is not full because the size is constant.

[image]

```
let tabBar = MDCTabBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 88, width: 414, height: 40))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureTabBar()
}

func configureTabBar() {
    tabBar.items = [
        UITabBarItem(title: "one", image: .none, tag: 0),
        UITabBarItem(title: "two", image: .none, tag: 0),
    ]

    tabBar.itemAppearance = .titledImages
    tabBar.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleBottomMargin]
    tabBar.sizeToFit()
    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
    tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    tabBar.rippleColor = UIColor.red
    tabBar.bottomDividerColor = UIColor.lightGray
    tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.gray
    tabBar.selectedItemTintColor = UIColor.red

    view.addSubview(tabBar)
}
```

What options do I have to add in order to get the item to fill the tab bar like the example in the Material Components Tab?

Comment: Hi @caleb, can you share a photo of what you want it to be?

Comment: Hi @Emre Ciffci ! I added two photos!
The picture above is what I want, and the picture below is the view I have implemented.

Comment: You can simply create custom segmentedControl for this. Why you use tabBar?

Comment: The app I want to create is the book app. We need a tab bar to show the genre of the book. Help

Comment: I think you should use custom `segmentedControl`, check Bruno Faganello's Medium article -> https://medium.com/code-with-coffee/create-a-custom-segmented-control-6488400f8705 I hope it is works.

Comment: I made it through the < Bruno Faganello's Medium article > you attached. Thank you. But I will add one more question. I want to show different data cells on the screen every time the page changes. E.g I want to output A when the index is 0, and B when it is 1.
Where can I extract an index from this article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about add below code in configureTabBar()

```
tabBar.alignment = .justified
```

Edit:
MDCTabBar have property called "alignment", so according to documentation in MaterialComponents MDCTabBar.h and MDCTabBar.m:

> Property 'alignment' is Horizontal alignment of tabs within the tab bar. Changes are not animated. Default alignment is MDCTabBarAlignmentLeading. The default value is based on the position and is recommended for most applications

alignment is MDCTabBarAlignment enum type that have four kinds enum:

> 1. MDCTabBarAlignmentLeading -> Items are aligned on the leading edge and sized to fit their content
> 2. MDCTabBarAlignmentJustified -> Items are justified to equal size across the width of the screen. Overscrolling is disabled
>      for this alignment.
> 3. MDCTabBarAlignmentCenter -> Items are sized to fit their content and center-aligned as a group. If they do not fit in view,
>      they will be leading-aligned instead.
> 4. MDCTabBarAlignmentCenterSelected -> Tabs are center-aligned on the selected item.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you add more details for your solution?